# How Can I append filters to videoTrack of QuickBlox?

Tags: android, video, webrtc, quickblox

I am using QuickBlox Android SDK, version 3.0. My app need do face-detection or append some filters to video track. I have found some answers using OnQBVideoChatListener.

```
private OnQBVideoChatListener qbVideoChatListener = new OnQBVideoChatListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraDataReceive(byte[] videoData) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMicrophoneDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpponentVideoDataReceive(byte[] videoData) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpponentAudioDataReceive(byte[] audioData) {
        }

};
```

But I can't find it in any aar of QuickBlox Android SDK 3.0.

My question is :

1) Is it possible to get YUV byte data or OpenGL texture from video track for Android SDK 3.0?

2) How to write camera frame data back to video track?

Any help will be appriciated!

> Edit 1:

[vfite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2524727/vfite) is right. SurfaceViewRenderer.renderFrame(I420Frame frame) is the key to this question. So I extend a class from QBRTCSurfaceView.

```
public class CustomRTCSurfaceView extends QBRTCSurfaceView {
    private static final String TAG = "CustomRTCSurfaceView";

    public CustomRTCSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomRTCSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderFrame(VideoRenderer.I420Frame frame) {
        //append filters or do modification as you wish
        VideoRenderer.I420Frame newFrame = getNewFrame();
        super.renderFrame(newFrame);
    }
  }
```

But this only change the frame effect of current side, how to apply this effect to other side of the peer-to-peer connection? Is there any custom parameters mechanism I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can register QBRTCClientVideoTracksCallbacks on QBRTSession and receive own and opponent video track. To get actual frames from video track yuo can register video callback on video renderer using

```
currentSession.addVideoTrackCallbacksListener(this);

 @Override
 public void onRemoteVideoTrackReceive(QBRTCSession session, final QBRTCVideoTrack videoTrack, final Integer userID) {
    videoTrack = ..;
 }

 videoTrack.addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(new VideoRenderer.Callbacks() {
        @Override
        public void renderFrame(VideoRenderer.I420Frame i420Frame) {
            //then check if frame contains yuv format or oes
         if (frame.yuvFrame) {
              drawYUV(frame.width, frame.height, frame.yuvStrides,  frame.yuvPlanes);
         } else {
             drawOes(frame.textureId, frame.width, frame.height);
         }
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I've edit my question, can you make a comment?